# ImageMagick: define 16 million as colors

Tags: imagemagick

If I need to convert colors of my bmp image to be 16 million, which value exactly shall I provide?

I  mean I know that I can define colors directly like that:

```
magick convert myimg.png -colors 256 BMP:myimg_256.bmp
```

But in case of 16 million colors, what is the exact value?

Comment: Why would you define anything at all in that case

Comment: my application needs 128x128 icon with 24-bit depth. I am not able to change depth in magick (it is always fixed to 8-bit) but I found that 16.8 million is equivalent to 24-bit depth.

Comment: Ah yes your source is 256 colors

Comment: The number you are looking for might be `2^24 = 16777216`. But I'm not totally sure I understand your approach.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. In your magick command, the input image is PNG and the output is BMP, but you say you are trying to convert a BMP to RGB (24bit). This doesn't make much sense to me. Can you please clarify what image format and colorspace the input file is in, and what format and colorspace you want to convert it to?  Thanks.

Comment: If you have a PNG8 (Indexed/256 colors), and you want to convert it to PNG24 (RGB/16777216 colors), then try this: magick convert input.png PNG24:output.png

Comment: Also note -colors does not work upward so specifying 16 nillion colors actually does nothing.

Comment: @joojaa , yes u are right it doesn't work upward.

Comment: @Billy Kerr, I tried your idea but still the generated PNG is also 8 bit. Thank you all for your support.

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself.  How are you checking the bit depth? If you are opening it in Photoshop/GIMP, then if it shows 8bit, that means 8bits per channel. 8*3=24bit.  In other words, an 8bit RGB image is 24bit.

Comment: Also note if you want to convert from PNG8 directly to an RGB BMP, then you can try this: magick convert input.png -type truecolor output.bmp

Answer (score 1):

After some to-and-fro in the comments, I think I know what the real problem is here.  I don't think has it has anything to do with imagemagick or your commands failing. It's down to confusion over how many bits an RGB image actually has.

If you have an 8bit (Indexed colour/256 colour) image, and convert it to RGB (i.e. 16 million colours), then it will be output as an 8bit RGB image.

An RGB image has 3 channels, so it is 3 channels * 8bit = 24bit.  In software such as Photoshop or GIMP, this will show up as "RGB/8" in Photoshop, or "RGB color 8 bit" in GIMP.

You can verify this is the case. In Windows, you can right click an RGB/8bit image file, choose Properties, and click the Details tab.  The bit depth will be shown as 24bit.

Here's an example. The 256 colour (Indexed colour) image is on the left, and the ouput RGB/8bit file is on the right.

[image]

The command I used to generate the output RGB PNG was as follows:

```
magick convert input.png PNG24:output.png
```

If you want to ouptut an RGB BMP instead, then:

```
magick convert input.png -type truecolor output.bmp
```

Note: other commands may be possible, but these do work. I just checked them.